# Data structure of an OLAP cube

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

MDX newbie here. I'm trying to imagine the data structure of an OLAP cube. Here's my basic idea:

- the cube is a collection of data items
- each data item contains a set of numeric values that correspond to measures (some might be null)
- each data item optionally contains a record for every dimension of the cube; that record contains fields that correspond to dimension attributes.

Is that a valid mental model?

Comment: sounds like a reasonable way to visualize it - I think a lot of folks visualize a cube (because any further dimensions would be tricky!) and then think about slicing the cube up, or pintointing certain bits of the cube

Comment: I'd say it collects (generates) coordinates (aggregated data value) for an every possible slice of the cube.

Answer (score 1):

Some people (I know I do) use a cube as a visualization model method:

[image]

I realize it only covers 3 dimensions but that is about all most of us can think about !

Answer (score 0):

a very interesting discussion.
The cube is already an abstraction, a conceptual representation of a data model. So, if you imagine a cube, you already imagine an OLAP data structure at a high level of abstraction.
I may add that each cell of the cube stores a numerical value (measure) pointed out by a set of coordinates (dimensions), which are not optional.
On turn, a dimension can be organized in aggregation levels that form a hierarchy.